# Running fishers test on certain columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
SYMBOL INTENSITY1 CALL1     PVALUE1 INTENSITY2 CALL2    PVALUE2  INTENSITY3 CALL3     PVALUE3
1   CCL5         NA  <NA>          NA         NA  <NA>         NA 1125.518318     P 0.000943658
2 CYP2A6  141.73193     A 0.060419342   102.5146     A 0.08940508  227.369549     A 0.218983229
3 CYP2E1   57.67287     P 0.024710915   134.4076     P 0.06300000    6.090816     A 0.040000000
4   DDR1 3242.90209     P 0.000218932         NA  <NA>         NA 7015.297075     P 0.000218932
5  EPHB3   78.58733     A 0.234556513   453.3487     P 0.00222774  125.238085     A 0.418069378
```

I want to run the fishers test on each row limited to the columns of `PVALUE`. There are some factor columns such as `NA` or `P` which i would like to exclude.

I use the following code to calculate the p-values by Fisher's method

```
Fisher.test <- function(p) {
  Xsq <- -2*sum(log(p))
  p.val <- pchisq(Xsq, df = 2*length(p), lower.tail = FALSE)
  return(c( p.value = p.val)) #
}
```

It works fine when i do it for a data frame with all numeric columns(i,e containing only `PVALUE` columns)

```
data$Fisher's <- apply(data[,-1],1,function(x) Fisher.test(x))
```

How to do it for a mixed type of data. Thanks

**Deisred Output:**

```
    SYMBOL INTENSITY1 CALL1     PVALUE1 INTENSITY2 CALL2    PVALUE2  INTENSITY3 CALL3     PVALUE3        Fisher's
      CCL5       NA   <NA>       NA        NA     <NA>         NA   1125.518318   P       0.000943658  0.000943658
      CYP2A6  141.73193 A     0.060419342 102.5146  A      0.08940508  227.369549 A       0.218983229  0.03602191
      CYP2E1  57.67287  P  0.024710915    134.4076  P      0.06300000    6.090816 A       0.040000000  0.00358522
      DDR1    3242.90209 P 0.000218932         NA  <NA>         NA 7015.297075    P       0.000218932  0.0000008557
      EPHB3   78.58733   A 0.234556513    453.3487   P    0.00222774  125.238085  A       0.418069378  0.00982
```

Comment: All the `PVALUE` columns of a certain row, then display the result of all the columns corresponding to a particular row in the `Fisher's` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `grep()` to obtain the indices of your data frame names which correspond to `PVALUE` columns, then subset the data frame in your call to `apply()`:

```
p.cols <- grep("PVALUE", names(data))
data$Fishers <- apply(data[, names(data)[p.cols]], 1, function(x) Fisher.test(x))
```

Comment: If i need to skip the entries of zero in a row.

Comment: You are assigning the result of the `apply` operation back into the `data` data frame.  What would you like to do in the case of a row with all zeroes?

Comment: in that case it should be zero .

Comment: What about `NA` values?  How do you want to handle these?  I am asking this so that you don't have to come back again.

Comment: Retain as `NA`. Thanks.

Comment: One last question, if a row has only zero and NA values, should it return all zeroes?

Comment: only one zero or NA is enough in the `Fishers` column

Comment: The need to skip zeros from running through the `Fisher.test` is that it renders  the final result as zero . Suppose i have a row with (0.000,0.20,0.0034), the result in `Fishers` column is zero, which is not the case.

Comment: Wait...if the result is already zero, then why do you need to manually assign zero?  Now I'm confused.

Comment: I think u got my above line wrong. I mean to say that if my row contains any zero, it gives the final result as zero, which is very wrong. So i need to skip the zero entries and run the `Fisher.test` on non zero entries to get the correct result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94077/discussion-between-tim-biegeleisen-and-awaitedone).

Comment: Believe it or not, you might do well to open a new question.  This is a delicate data massaging problem and I think it could merit an entire question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.